# how to use Content_type, video/mp2t in http response?

Tags: python, http, http-headers, mime-types

I am preparing response to a http request to send video and receiving error: Broken Pipe

```
 if self.path.endswith(".ts"):  
     f = open("filename.ts", 'r')
     self.send_response(200)
     self.send_header('Content-Type', "video/mp2t")
     self.end_headers()
     self.wfile.write(f.read())
     return
```

Same response below works fine.

```
 if self.path.endswith(".mov"):  
            f = open("filename.mov", 'r')
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', "video/mpeg")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(f.read())
            return
```

I suspect it is related to mimetype issue. Can any one suggest me how can i use video/mp2t with baseHttpServer ??

Comment: And again you're randomly guessing that "broken pipe" comes from the MIME type? You already asked another question on this. If you just asked "What means a broken pipe error?" people would give you better answers.

Comment: I am not randomly guessing. Content-Type, video/mpeg is working where as Content-Type, video/mp2t is not working and I think broken pipe is a more generalised error. The actual error that provoked me to guess about mimetypes is ERROR:404: Content not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of mpeg2ts, client(Quicktime in Browser) requesting specific byte ranges in multiple GET requests. preparing the response as per the requested byte ranges fixed the issue.

Comment: I am also having this problem.  Can you elaborate on how you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'll give it a try. "Broken pipe" on the server side usually means that the client closes the connection while the server is still sending data. From your previous question, I assume your client is a browser (using the `<video>` tag). That most probably means that the browser does not support playback of MPEG transport streams. Actually I haven't heard of any browser that supports it.

Maybe you should try to stream an Ogg Theora video (MIME type "video/theora") for testing - Firefox 3.1+ supports this out of the box. If that works, your server implementation is correct.

Comment: here is the more info: I could play ts file with video tag on client side with safari. The only difference is: in my success scenario, I was using Apache as my web server and modfied httpd.conf to add line, AddType video/MP2T .ts

Comment: I am figuring out why my baseHttpServer unable to recognize mimetype, video/mp2t and trying to add to it.

Comment: @neuron: `BaseHTTPServer.send_header` doesn't restrict the header value in any way. What you specified will be sent to the client as is. Maybe MIME types are case-sensitive?? Try "video/MP2T" in your Python code. Or check the difference between Apache and your solution with Wireshark.

Comment: Thank you so much for the continuous support and quick responses.